# How to show dynamic number value as a star rating in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to show dynamic number value as a star in the HTML field.Please a give a working example.

Comment: search in google 
try it by yourself 
then if u have mistakes ask in stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

These kind of questions are not encouraged, please take a [quick stackoverflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how things work around here.

I will try to answer your question - from what I could understand, you want to implement some sort of rating system in your app. I would recommend using `ng2-bootstrap`'s [rating component](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/rating).

Comment: i am using this syntax to define directive but it's showing a error like this directives: [ Rating], error:---"Uncaught ReferenceError: Rating is not defined" how can i solve it